# copy file from window to ubuntu

Tags: copy

I have a STL file in my c drive "Window", and I was trying to copy that file to the Ubuntu, however it shown error message, what should I do?

[image]

Comment: I recommend access the file from Ubuntu instead of starting from Windows and copy to Ubuntu. From there you can cp the file.

Comment: Please add screenshot to the question instead of as a link. Are you triSurface folder exist? Are you sure you want it there? Probably you want personal files on your home folder.

Comment: @ Marco. dont use /TriSurface but use TriSurface/rest/of/the/path instead. That should solve your problem.

Comment: On my drive I setup a separate 9 GB NTFS partition for files to be indirectly shared between Ubuntu (`/mnt/e`) and Windows 10 WSL (drive letter `E:`). I did this after exhausting all other methods of direct file sharing. This is something all dual-boot users might want to consider.

Answer (score 2):

First, please do not copy text as pictures.

Second, you're attempting to copy the file to `/triSurface`, which is probably not a directory that exists, nor *should* it exist.

Your users files are typically in `/home/username/`, often abbreviated `~`.

You probably want to copy the file to `~/triSurface/`, not `/triSurface`. If `~/triSurface` does not exist, you can create the directory with `mkdir ~/triSurface`.

In general only root is able to modify files outside of `/tmp` and your home directory. `/tmp` is, as name indicates, used only for temporary files, and not intended for persistent storage.

Comment: As i see his screenshot he is copying to his homefolder. He only got the path wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
cp /mnt/c/Users/leewp/Desktop/cylinder3.stl triSurface/
```

Because you are already on the path. And the triSurface already excist.
Except if you really want to make /triSurface. Which i would not recommend.

Comment: Full PATH of the file would then be : "/home/marcolwp/OpenFOAM/marcolwp-5.0/run/mySim/EstaMesh/constant/triSurface/cylinder3.stl"